# How do i get the value of <select> from a populated option?

Tags: php, html

Currently stuck on this one.

I'm trying to $_POST the selected option where the option is populated.

```
**HTML:**
<label style="color:white">Date of Birth:</label>
<select id="months"></select>
<select id="days"></select>
<select id="years"></select>

**SCRIPT for the month populate:**
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++){
        $('#months').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }
```

I tried, $dmonth = $_POST['months']; but i get Undefined Index.

Fixing the Undefined Index with if(isset($_POST['months'])) gives me an empty value.

Next thing i tried is getting the text value, by:

```
$('#months').find(":selected").text();
```

Is there a way to get the text value and pass it to a PHP variable?

Comment: You can't read with PHP an input populated by client side. You must put the select inside a form and you can read the $_POST value with PHP after the form is submitted. If you don't want to submit a form but read the select value every time ii is select then you have to use a JavaScript function with fetch or xhr that send the value to a PHP page for read the value.

Comment: How are you submitting those fields? Using ajax? If it's a "normal" form, then you need to give the selects a `name` attribute (which is what it will be stored under in the `$_POST`-array), or they won't be submitted at all.

Comment: It's nice that you are polite, but it doesn't really answer any of our questions or give us anything more to go on.

Comment: Hehe. To be honest Sir @MagnusEricksson, this is my first time trying HTML's and PHP's. By "normal" form Sir, do you mean <div class="form-group"> ?

Comment: No, I'm talking about a basic [html form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form) without using JavaScript to submit it (like using Ajax), but never mind since your issue seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have already a form where you put your select.

For populate options, you can consider a script like:

```
for (i = 1; i < 13; i++){
    $('#months').append($('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
}
```

After that you can get the selected option text, doing something like this (JS)

```
let selectedOptionText = ($("#months").val()) ? $("#months").find("option[value='"+$("#months").val()+"']").html() : '';
```

If you want to pass this val on server side, you should consider adding an hidden param in your HTML form (just one of possible way).

But.. just a question.. why use this approach, when you can simply use an input with type="date"? This would also help you with formatting checks and server side usage.

Hope to be helpful

Comment: I kinda like the drop-down style so i tried it but then I changed it to:

<label style="color:white">Date of Birth:</label>
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">

which is simpler and is also mobile friendly.

Thanks sir!

Comment: I'll still try the drop-down using your suggestion of hidden param, I'll compare which is better in mobile browsers. Thanks Sir @Francesco.